# ComboBox Input String format exception when DataGrid row selection is blank

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is populated from a SQL Server database and I have a mouse double click event that opens up a new window and populates the `Textboxes` and `ComboBoxes`.

I have one small issue. if the column named "RTTYPE" is blank for the row selected I'm getting a `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format` and then the `ComboBox` shows the first value item from the list.

I would like the `ComboBox` to remain blank if the row selected is blank. Please help!

```
        private void dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // User double clicks on DataGrid Row
        // Open new Window
        // Populate selected textboxes with selected datarow
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

        var windowToOpen = new Window1();

        if (gd != null)
        {
            // Textboxes
            windowToOpen.txt_RowRecrd.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_acctnumber.Text = row_selected["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_analyst.Text = row_selected["TX_EMPLOYEE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_custname.Text = row_selected["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_address.Text = row_selected["PREM_ADDR"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Status.Text = row_selected["Status"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = row_selected["OPENED"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_deadline.Text = row_selected["DEADLINE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_DaysOpen.Text = row_selected["DaysOpen"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_DateResolved.Text = row_selected["DATERSLVD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_revcls.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_WFMissuedBy.Text = row_selected["NM_USER"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_firstreview.Text = row_selected["FR_DT_FIRSTREV"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_Latestupdate.Text = row_selected["FR_TS_LATESTUPD"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_reviewNotes.Text = row_selected["FR_CMMNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_ResolutionNotes.Text = row_selected["COMMENT"].ToString();


            // ComboBoxes
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter Status_data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT RPTID, ReportType FROM [hb_RptType]", connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                Status_data.Fill(ds, "t");

                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["t"].DefaultView;
                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.DisplayMemberPath = "ReportType";
                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedValuePath = "RPTID";
                windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedValue = row_selected["RPTTYPE"].ToString();

                // windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = 3; //  Convert.ToInt32( row_selected["RPTTYPE"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            windowToOpen.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the `null` for a `Selected Value` of `ComboBox` it throws an exception. If your data is just a plain string, you can use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`. Or perform a null-check:

```
if(row_selected["RPTTYPE"] is string rateType) windowToOpen.cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedValue = rateType;
else UtilityRptTyp.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: My ["RPTTYPE"] column is an `Int` and I replaced `string` with `int` and now my `ComboBox` is blank and I get the same exception message if the row selected is `null`

Comment: SelectedValue is always a string. So though your  ["RPTTYPE"] is int, the SelectedValue of ComboBox is still a string. So you should ether cast the rateType to string on assigning it to SelectedValue, or you can try and keep my code as it is wit string, not int. is string will cast it to string "1", for example and assign it to SelectedValue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what I need to do. When I use the code you provided, I still get an exception message and 1 on the list appears just like it did before. I would like the `ComboBox` to remain blank.

Comment: It could be useful, if you'd write, what exception do you get.
You should ether cast your row_selected["RPTTYPE"] to string, or, if you are populating ComboBox with ints, you can try using SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue.
ComboBox has 3 options for selection. SelectedIndex is int and unselected ComboBox is SelectedIndex = -1. SelectedItem is object of any type and unselected ComboBox is SelectedItem = null (but you possibly will need to set ComboBox.Text to ""). SelectedValue is a string and you can not make it unselected. Mind that and you'll find a solution for your problem.